# Templating throws out a lot of errors

Tags: c++, templates

I am creating a helper namespace for one of my projects, i wanted it to be able to use all types like ints, floats, doubles etc. But it seems like i just cant get the templating right.

Anyways, here is my current code, my compiler doesn't spit out errors about the file itself, though when i compile it it spits out hundreds of errors in other files.
These errors aren't there when i remove the templating in the file:

```
#include "..\util\Logger.hpp"

namespace gm
{
    namespace math
    {
        namespace MathHelper
        {
            // Value of Pi
            const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841972;
            // Value of euler
            const double E =  2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572;

            // Convert radians to degrees
            template <typename T>
            T Rad2Deg(T angle)
            {
                return angle * (180 / (T)PI);
            }

            // Convert degrees to radians
            template <typename T>
            T Deg2Rad(T angle)
            {
                return angle * ((T)PI / 180);
            }

            // Clamp a value in between the given min and max
            template <typename T>
            T Clamp(T value, T min, T max)
            {
                if(min > max) { gm::util::Logger::DisplayError("Invalid argument in MathHelper::Clamp, max is over min"); }
                if(value < min) { value = min; }
                if(value > max) { value = max; }
                return value;
            }

            // Exponentiate value a with value b
            template <typename T>
            T Exp(T a, int b)
            {
                if(b < 0) { gm::util::Logger::DisplayError("Invalid argument in MathHelper::Exp, b must be positive"); }
                T value = a;
                for(int i = 1; i < b; i++) { value *= a; }
                return value;
            }

            // Get the absolute value of the value passed
            template <typename T>
            T Abs(T a, T b)
            {
                if(value < 0) { value = -value;
                return value;
            }
        };
    };
};
```

I put the compile errors in this paste: http://pastebin.com/AxwmDyDh

Comment: What errors? Also, don't use backslashes in includes.

Comment: I really had to chuckle when I read the title of that question.

Comment: Why are you using templates? Do you expect people to pass a string or an Employee to these functions? Are you writing these just for practice? If you just need the absolute value of something, it's been done already. Finally, show the first set of errors and the line of calling code that produces them.

Comment: I prefer to throw my errors out as well :P

Comment: Does `if(value < 0) { value = -value;` really have a missing brace?

Comment: namespace {} doesn't/shouldn't have a ; after it

Comment: Just look at Deg2Rad and Rad2Deg - if I pass an integer to one of those, why does it mean I want an integer back? I would just make these methods take and return doubles, then rely on argument promotion.

Comment: I added a pastebin link with the compile errors, none of them come when the templated functions are removed

Comment: Don't use pastebin, post them here!

Comment: @Neil i overlooked that, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deg/rad conversion functions won't work right if you pass in an `int` for `T` because PI will get truncated to int before doing the conversion. I can't quite make out why you have that in there.

Using variable names like `min` and `max` will cause problems if you have a `using namespace` anywhere.

Your `abs` function is missing a closing `}` on the `if`. That could cause errors at the call point.

Answer (score 1):

A curly brace is missed in `if`.

```
if(value < 0) { value = -value;
```